# ImportError: No module named git after reformatting laptop

Tags: python, git, gitpython

My laptop has been formatted and a new OS was installed, and since then I have gotten this error:

```
ImportError: No module named git
```

This refers to a Python code that simply imports git.

Location of git before my laptop was formatted: `/usr/local/bin/git`
Location of git after the laptop was formatted: `/usr/bin/git`

How / what do I change in my Python code to refer to the right path?

Comment: The `git` command line option is *not a Python module*. You'll need to install that separately.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `git` module is *not the same thing* as the `git` command line executable. They happen to have the same name and cover related tasks, but they are distinct software packages.

I'm going to assume that the `git` module your code is importing is the one provided by the [GitPython project](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You'll need to install that project, see their [installation instructions](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro.html#installing-gitpython):

```
# pip install gitpython
```

Answer (score 7):

In my cas, I installed pythong2-git, it solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-git
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, running apt install python-git in Terminal/CLI fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

[GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython)’s git repo is available on GitHub, which can be browsed at:

https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython
and cloned using:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython git-python
```

Initialize all submodules to obtain the required dependencies with:

```
$ cd git-python
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

In Centos7 (might also work in Redhat System), if you are using Python2.7 :

```
sudo yum install epel-release

sudo yum install python-pip

sudo yum install GitPython.noarch
```

The above command is to install `gitpython` in **Python2**